# Spring Thymeleaf how can I save a spcific value in database using select and option html tags

Tags: html, mysql, spring, thymeleaf

I have a jobs table in my database (mysql). The table contains an id, a varchar title (admin, project lead, etc) and a varchar roles column. The roles column is used by spring security during the login process and can have two values `ROLES_ADMIN` and `ROLES_USER`.

I have created an edit page where the admin can edit any existing job. What I want to do is to limit the choices to user and admin but instead of displaying ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER the select tag should display Admin and User.

Something like this:

option 1 displays text Admin saves ROLE_ADMIN in the database

option 2 displays text User saves ROLE_USER in database

Currently my tag looks something like this

```
<select name="role">
    <option th:each="job: ${jobs}" th:value="${job.role}" th:text="${job.role}"></option>
</select>
```

It displays ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN and saves them as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change

```
th:text="${job.role}"
```

into the text you want to display and keep `th:value` as is.

For that you can for example make a getter in your Job class

```
public String getDisplayRole() {
  return ""; // split role on _, take second element and make title case for example
}
```

and then `th:text="${job.displayRole)"`

Comment: so `th:text="${Admin}"` ? Wouldn't that save Admin in the database?

Comment: no, the value in `th:value` should be saved to the database

Comment: Doesn't work. Select shows up blank and it doesn't change anything when I edit

Comment: any errors in console? is the getDisplayRole() method getting called?

Comment: No errors. It is. Any idea how I could give th:value a specific value.

Comment: you can call a method in there the same way or just set it yourself `th:value="my_val"`. In any case the `th:value` should stay ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER and the `th:text` should be the displayed text. You should check the generated <option> tag and see if the text and value are set correctly.

Comment: Solved it. Because the entries were not unique I needed to add a new attribute in @requestmethod which took a list of roles from the database and use a group by query to only display one value of each type.